# What is the best data type to store the result int*long in c++

Tags: c++, types

What is the best configurable datatype to assign the result of int* unsigned long

For example:

```
int RValue1 = 4096;
unsigned long RValue2 = 1048576;
```

I want to store result of RValue2*RValue1 in a variabl.

I tried the following:

```
int RValue1 = 4096;
unsigned long RValue2 = 1048576;
long long result1 = RValue2*RValue1; //resulted 0
int64_t result2 = RValue2*RValue1;// resulted 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by *configurable datatype*?

Comment: You can use the `auto` specifier and see what the compiler makes of it. In your case chances are it will be `unsigned long`.

Comment: @Ron No chances about it.  `unsigned long` has a higher rank than `int` so it will always be a `unsigned long`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on https://wandbox.org/permlink/arDLtyx8cXu7g5Kl. What is your architecture? What is your `sizeof(unsigned long)`?

Answer (score 2):

Int64 is fine. You're getting 0 because your code first calculates the 32 bit product (which is 0) then stores it in int64 variable. Try this way:

```
int64_t result3 = (int64_t)(RValue2)*RValue1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int RValue1 = 4096;                 // 0x1000 
unsigned long RValue2 = 1048576;    // 0x10`0000
long long result1 = RValue2*RValue1;// 0x1`0000`0000
```

With the above the multiplication is being done using `unsigned long` math, even though the result is stored in a `long long`.  The result overflowed `unsigned long` 32-bit math so it "wrapped around" to 0.  Had `unsigned long` been 64-bit, no problem would have been noted.

With mixed integer types, I recommend instead of casting, as it can sometimes narrow the type used in the computation, multiply by 1 of the target type to insure the calculation is done with *at least* as wide as the target's type.

```
long long result1 = 1LL*RValue2*RValue1;
```